# Hibernate exception -- could not execute update query

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I have the following method, using Hibernate, that's driving me nuts.  It's not updating my database correctly, and I cannot see what the problem.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
public boolean changePassword(String username, String password) {
    HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) request.getSession()
            .getServletContext().getAttribute("sessionFactory");
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    try {
        request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        Query myQuery = session.createQuery("update Administrator "
                + "set password = " + password + " where username = "
                + username);
        if (myQuery.executeUpdate() == 1) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return false;
}
```

Here is what I have in my console:

```
Hibernate: update login set password=password1 where username=frank
could not execute update query
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using parametrized queries to solve this issue.

```
Query myQuery = session.createQuery("update Administrator "
                + "set password = :password where username = :username");
```

I think the code for setting parameters is

```
myQuery.setParameter("username", username);

myQuery.setParameter("password", password);
```

Comment: +1. If not using parameterized query an sql injection is knocking on the door.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be the parameter values escaped? Also: why don't you use `setParameter()` instead of constructing the whole query by hand? It will do all the necessary escaping for you. The code could be then:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("update Administrator set password =\
                               :password where username = :username");
q.setParameter("password", password);
q.setParameter("username", username);
```